# ssl cert validation in powershell 7

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, f5, powershell-7.0

so question not really about powershell, but maybe how to manage this:
below is a script (well parts pulled out of a script we use to manage our F5 load balancer)

```
$modules = @("F5-LTM","TunableSslValidator","POSH-SSH")
$apiVersion = "15.1.0.2"
$headers = @{"Content-Type"="application/json"}
$credentials = Get-Credential 
try
{
        ForEach($module in $modules)
        {
                import-module $module -ErrorAction Stop
        }
}
catch
{
        Write-host "[ " -NoNewline
        write-host "FAIL" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-host " ] " -NoNewline
        write-host "Importing Powershell Modules"
        write-host $_.Exception -ForegroundColor Red
        exit
}
Write-host "[ " -NoNewline
write-host " OK " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
Write-host " ] " -NoNewline
write-host "Importing Powershell Modules"


$uri = "https://F5hostname/mgmt/tm/ltm/monitor/https/my-site_https_monitor?ver=$apiVersion"

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Handle Cert Warning
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'ServerCertificateValidationCallback').Type)
{
$certCallback = @"
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class ServerCertificateValidationCallback
    {
        public static void Ignore()
        {
            if(ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback ==null)
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                    delegate
                    (
                        Object obj, 
                        X509Certificate certificate, 
                        X509Chain chain, 
                        SslPolicyErrors errors
                    )
                    {
                        return true;
                    };
            }
        }
    }
"@
    Add-Type $certCallback
 }
[ServerCertificateValidationCallback]::Ignore()

Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $uri -insecure -Headers $headers -Credential $credentials ErrorAction Stop -UseBasicParsing
```

this works if you run with powershell 5.1 but fails with the following error in powershell 7.0.1

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

the f5 does have a untrusted cert - and i am looking to resolve that, but i am using TunableSslValidator and i have that cert validation block in there because we had issues in powershell 5 as well, but we trust this internal resource and i was willing to ignore the cert issues.

is there a way to bypass this in powershell 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just faced the same problem last friday: after a look in the docs for pwsh 7.0 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7 I saw that a new switch "-SkipCertificateCheck" was introduced and this worked to ignore cert validation.

Comment: I haven't tested this on this script but i have used -skipcertificationcheck on pwsh 7 with success so I will mark this solved using pwsh 7